# QT cannot open output file debug\trud1.exe: Permission denied

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, permission-denied

Using debug I can run my project only one time. After that every time I get error:

> cannot open output file debug\trud1.exe: Permission denied error:
>
> ld returned 1 exit status

I close running Qt projects but seems like I can not close this one even via task manager (theres no tasks trud1.exe).
Explorer does not let me delete trud1.exe because it is used by my "System" (i can not kill this process).
Restarting Qt does not help me, only restarting computer does.
Please help me solve my problem.

Comment: did you try to launch it in release? is it debug only problem?

Comment: 1) My project folders are in skip list of my antivirus.
2) In release everying is ok so its only debug problem.

Comment: Do you think your program is being executed  correctly? Is exit code 0 in debug?

Comment: yes, C:\..\debug\trud1.exe завершился с кодом 0

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you have to close the program you've launched before.

Look it isn't running on background.

Comment: im sure its not. i can not stop it more then one time and can not connect to the process.